# Reload flickity after replace html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flickity

I run multiple flickity and it is correctly run in the first html code. while the `.boxgallery` replace with new html `.boxgallery` after click on button, isn't correct run flickity.

what do i do? (Unchanged replaceWith js)

```js
var $carousel = $('.gallery').flickity();
var isFlickity = true;
$('.button').on( 'click', function()
{
 //Clearing previous contents
 $carousel.flickity('destroy');
  
 $('.boxgallery').replaceWith('<div class="boxgallery"><div class="gallery"><div class="gallery-cell"></div><div class="gallery-cell"></div><div class="gallery-cell"></div></div></div>');

 // init new Flickity
 $carousel.flickity();
});
```

```css
@import url(http://flickity.metafizzy.co/flickity.css);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.gallery {
    width: 200px;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    counter-reset: gallery-cell;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
}

.gallery-cell {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: #8C8;
  counter-increment: gallery-cell;
}

.gallery-cell:before {
  content: counter(gallery-cell);
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 160px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.gallery-nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gallery-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #09F;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.gallery-nav li.is-selected {
  background: #09F;
  color: white;
}

.gallery-nav li:hover {
  background: #ADF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.0.5/flickity.pkgd.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.0.5/flickity.min.css">

<button class="button">Re Create Flickity</button>

<div class="boxgallery">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
    <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
    <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
    <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
    <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
    <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
    <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/74bcqf6x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [destroy](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/api.html#destroy) demos for toggling Flickity on and off
But I think you're better off using [resize](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/api.html#resize)